# SSL certificates on Windows

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, servicestack

This may be more appropriate on ServerFault, if so I'll gladly move it.
I am trying to set up SSL for a self-hosted ServiceStack service (similar to WCF). I have followed many tutorials about creating certificates etc. I have managed to bind a certificate to the port I am using. However, whenever I browse to the site, I get the following error:

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

```
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

I then tried binding one of the pre-existing certificates on my machine to the port. The procedure I followed was to run

> netsh http show sslcert
>   which included these bindings:

```
IP:port                 : 0.0.0.0:443 
Certificate Hash        : 9874718543a78369896977e06ceaee90a5ab0516
Application ID          : {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914} 
Certificate Store Name  : MY 

IP:port                 : 0.0.0.0:44300 
Certificate Hash        : 073f81ad5fe1140663a8838ae54a805765065074
Application ID          : {214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74a} 
Certificate Store Name  : MY
```

Which I assume are 'default' certificates and bindings. If I browse to https://localhost:443 I get the IIS7 welcome screen.

I bound the same certificate to the port my console app is using, but when I browse there I get the (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long) error.

If I change my app to use port 44300, I get the same error.

Can anyone provide guidance on why this is happening?